# What is Apsidal Vector?

Tags: vectors, terminology, definition

I have recently heard of [Apsidal Vectors](https://www.google.com/search?as_epq=apsidal+vectors). I was searching about it through internet. I had found [the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gjSdIwOsnic) in YT. I had found similar question in [PF](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/apsidal-vectors.187586/). But, the PF answer wasn't clear to me. I am just going to state what I understood from that YT video.

If I think of a elliptical or any kind of circle, and imagine a center line (related to centroid) in that elliptical than that center line is Apsidal Distance or line.

It might be related to following center line.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When one object orbits another, the [apsides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apsis) are the two points in the orbit where the distance between the two bodies has a minimum or a maximum value. The apsis at which the distance is a minimum is called the periapsis and the apsis at which the distance is a maximum is called the apoapsis (or sometimes apapsis).

An apsidal vector is the vector (direction and distance) from the primary body to the orbiting body at periapsis or at apoapsis. The line joining the periapsis and the apoapsis is called the [apse line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apse_line) or line of apsides.

Note that an open orbit will have a periapsis but not an apoapsis since the distance between the two bodies is unbounded.